# accessing xml attributes in xsl

Tags: php, xslt

i've this xml code:

```
<title xml:lang="ar">أربيك</title>
<title xml:lang="en">English</title>
```

which i'm formatting in xsl:

```
<div class="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="root/title"/>
</div>
```

however, this^ only displays the arabic title, and not the english one. i tried this code:

```
<div class="title">
        <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang"><xsl:value-of select="root/title"/> </xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

but with this^ code, it doesn't display the titles at all. what is the correct way to display both the english and the arabic titles?

Comment: A condensed, self-contained, copy&pastable example would be nice (i.e. we copy the entire code, execute it and see the problem).

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a shot, simple and complete solution.

Comment: I think your first attempt was in the right direction. Check my answer to see how it can correctly be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will work.

Source XML:

```
$xmlDoc = <<< XML
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="ar">أربيك</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">English</title>
</titles>
XML;
```

XSL Stylesheet with template matching any title nodes in the document

```
$xslDoc = <<< XSL
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
           <h1>Titles</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <div class="{@xml:lang} title">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
XSL;
```

And transformation with PHP:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($xmlDoc);
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->loadXML($xslDoc);
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

will give:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<h1>Titles</h1>
    <div class="ar title">أربيك</div>
    <div class="en title">English</div>
```

**EDIT**: modified title template to use the xml:lang attribute as class attribute, so you can style it with CSS. If you need more complex styling, write another template that matches the attribute (as shown by Volker).

Comment: gives the same error `Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): element template only allowed as child of stylesheet`

Comment: ...not if you've copy&pasted Gordon's example - where <template> is a child of <stylesheet>.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [for-each](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp):

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/title">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am not 100% sure but I think `value-of` will only get the value of **one** element, and if several are selected, it just gets the value of the first one.

Comment: thanks, this worked, but i want to apply different styles to both the titles. how would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

A title template will be the best way to do this:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
  <div class="title">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

You *could* use `xsl:for-each` to achieve the same, but a template is the idiomatic xsl.

Comment: it gives the error: `Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): element template only allowed as child of stylesheet`

Comment: @fuz3d - indeed. It should be part of a stylesheet. This code I posted is a single template, without the `xsl:stylesheet` declaration. The full stylesheet would like what @Gordon posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one template that matches a specific node. In that case the matching templates are prioritized and only the template with the highest priority is used. If you don't specifically set a priority there are built-in rules to determine the priority, see [5.5 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict).

E.g. if you have the two templates

1. <xsl:template match="title">...</xsl:template>
2. <xsl:template match="title[@xml:lang='ar']">...</xsl:template>

they both match `<title xml:lang="ar">أربيك</title>`.
But the one testing the xml:lang attribute (template #2) is "more specific than the most common kind of pattern" and gets a higher priority than the template that simply matches all <title> elements (template #1).
Therefore template #2 is selected.
For `<title xml:lang="en">title 2</title>` there is only one matching template (template #1) which is therefore selected.

self-contained example:

```
<?php
$proc = <<< XSL
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <h2>template #1: <xsl:value-of select="."/></h2>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title[@xml:lang='ar']">
    <h1>template #2: <xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
XSL;
$proc = getProcessor($proc);

$doc = <<< XML
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="ar">أربيك</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">english title</title>
</titles>
XML;
$doc = getDocument($doc);

echo $proc->transformToXML($doc);


function getDocument($xml) {
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
  $doc->loadxml($xml);
  return $doc;
}

function getProcessor($xml) {
  $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
  $proc->importStylesheet(getDocument($xml));
  return $proc;
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <h1>template #2: أربيك</h1>
    <h2>template #1: english title</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the shortest, complete solution, that is also completely in the spirit of XSLT is the following**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="title">
    <div class="title">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (just wrapping the provided XML fragment into a single top element):

```
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="ar">أربيك</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">English</title>
</titles>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<div class="title">أربيك</div>
<div class="title">English</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your first attempt was in the right direction: just copy the @xml:lang and apply CSS style later. So this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="titles">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <div class="title">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@xml:lang"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With proper input (from Dimitre):

```
<titles>
    <title xml:lang="ar">أربيك</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">English</title>
</titles>
```

Output:

```
<html>
<div class="title" xml:lang="ar">أربيك</div>
<div class="title" xml:lang="en">English</div>
</html>
```

Or this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="titles">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <div class="title" lang="{@xml:lang}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
<div class="title" lang="ar">أربيك</div>
<div class="title" lang="en">English</div>
</html>
```